# Harry Potter fan fiction where Harry is forced to bear Voldemort’s child

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

In this Harry is forced to bear Voldemort’s child but the truth is that Severus gives Harry a potion which changes Voldemort’s magical signature to that of Severus’. Harry and Severus have been seeing each other and Harry bears Severus’ child. Also poppy adopts him and is distantly related to Fleur Delacour.

I read it on fanfiction.net only. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question?cb=1) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Comment: I am completely speechless about this title. I definitely do not want to know the thought process that lead to the existence of this story.

Comment: @Fabian - Boredom and deviancy

Comment: Are people downvoting this just because it sounds like a crappy story? I don't think that's what downvotes on questions are for.

Comment: @Fabian Downvotes are for whatever you want them to be for, with that said the tooltip does state "this is not useful" and I can see how some people would think that.

Comment: @Fabian Same here. Uuuuuurgh!

Comment: To quote The Life of Brian, "Where is the baby going to gestate? In a box?"

Comment: There are worse Garfield fan fics, TBH. I've read one.